# how to convert the Elasticsearch json output in a table?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm using Head plugin for ELASTICSEARCH for running queries.
I want to convert in a table the output of the query.

The part that I need is just the "hits" object array
where the columns are the fields that I have specified into the query:
"http.date","src_shift","@timestamp","src_tz".

is there any tool or plugin to do that?

below a brief output of query:

```
"took": 2418,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 3503,
    "successful": 3503,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 2524,"max_score": 9.194927,"hits": [
        {
            "_index": "$002555","_type": "pcap","_id": "AVAJJphp2MeWtoWCbQYG","_score": 9.194927,"fields": {
                "src_shift": [
                    1],"http.date": [
                    "Fri, 12 Jun 2015 22:40:54 GMT"],"@timestamp": [
                    1434147980397],"src_tz": [
                    "Europe/Warsaw"]}},{
            "_index": "$002555","_type": "pcap","_id": "AVAJJphp2MeWtoWCbQYH","_score": 9.194927,"fields": {
                "src_shift": [
                    1],"http.date": [
                    "Fri, 12 Jun 2015 22:40:54 GMT"],"@timestamp": [
                    1434147980397],"src_tz": [
                    "Europe/Warsaw"]}},...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the head plugin, on your Any Request tab, you can use the Result Transformer section located just below the Query section. By default it returns the whole JSON response.

[image: Result Transformer section]

You can modify that and massage the response to return whatever you want. In your case, if you replace the default `return root;` by the code below, you'll get what you want:

```
return root.hits.hits.map(function(hit) {
    var values = [];
    for (var field in hit.fields) {
        values.push(hit.fields[field]);
    }
    return values.join(",");
});
```

The output should be

```
1,"Fri, 12 Jun 2015 22:40:54 GMT",1434147980397,"Europe/Warsaw"
1,"Fri, 12 Jun 2015 22:40:54 GMT",1434147980397,"Europe/Warsaw"
...
```

Comment: that's great, thanks! do you have also any advice to manage bucket results?

Comment: Do you mean the aggregation buckets? What do you want to do?

Comment: yes, if the response is an aggregation results I have no fields but a bucket collection , so I would to list the key and doc_count

Comment: You can do exactly the same just use `root.aggregations` instead of `root.hits.hits`. Feel free to create another question with a specific use case, if needed.

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to achieve this from the query json itself. I found the [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-transform.html) documentation from 1.7, but that's old. There's nothing about it in the 5.1 docs. Can anybody give me any hints for this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a utility in Kibana called `tabify` that converts ElasticSearch results into tabular form. You can find its implementation here: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/ui/public/agg_response/tabify/tabify.js

Comment: By the way, I recently released a standalone implementation of the tabify function https://github.com/datavis-tech/es-tabify